# jqGrid hidden key column not posting to server on edit or delete

Tags: jqgrid, key, hidden

I have added a hidden key column apart from the id column in the jqGrid. When I click submit on edit or delete dialogues the hidden key column is not posted to the server.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand the problem you should add the following properties in the hidden column:

```js
editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: false }
```

I recommend you additionally verify the value of `id` attributes of rows (`<tr>` elements) of the grid. You can use Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to do this. If the values of `id` attributes are what you need, then you can examine `id` value which will be posted to the server during editing and delete operations. The value should be correct. If you like to rename `id` parameter to for example `myKey` then you can use jqGrid option `prmNames: {id: "myKey"}`.

You don't posted the code which you use to create jqGrid. The `id` property of `jsonReader` will be used during reading of input data if you use `datatype: "json"`. If the input data contains `myKey` property instead of `id` property then you can use `jsonReader: { id: "myKey" }` to inform jqGrid where to get rowids. In the case you can **remove** unneeded hidden column having `key: true`. It will reduce the size of DOM of the page.